# Weird otuput of the lm() function in R

Tags: r, regression

I receive such a weird output from lm() after typing the below code:
[image]

I should be expecting something similar to a table with estimated parameters and errors. However such thing happens.
I don't know what can be wrong. Therefore I would appreciate your help. I attach the other screen with the data. It's curious that
 `59 = 1 + 30*2 - 2`, which is an `intercept +2*number of obs - 2` degrees of freedom.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of your data is of type character. Convert those to numeric and rerun the regression.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective code. Additionally, questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without this, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed. Please construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it.

Answer (score 3):

All your "ln_" columns are "character", causing the lm function to treat them as factors (if im correct, pretty new myself as well)

Comment: I do think that is the case.

Comment: The question that was asked was "I don't know what can be wrong", which I pointed out. While I do not supply all the steps needed to do a complete correct analysis, my answer gives a pointer towards the right direction, leading to a better learning experience in my opinion.

Comment: That can be the reason! Thanks.